# OpenGL - DDS and sRGB colorspace

Tags: opengl, dds-format

I have checked a few examples of DDS loader implementation. Typically, detecting DXT format looks like this:

```
if (ddsHeader.ddsPixelFormat.dwFlags & DDSF_FOURCC) 
{
    switch (ddsHeader.ddsPixelFormat.dwFourCC) 
    {
    case FOURCC_DXT1:
    {
        format = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT;
        break;
    }
    //etc
```

Detecting standard RGB format looks this way:

```
if (ddsHeader.ddsPixelFormat.dwFlags & DDPF_RGB) 
{
    if (ddsHeader.ddsPixelFormat.dwRGBBitCount == 24 &&
        ddsHeader.ddsPixelFormat.dwRBitMask == 0x000000FF &&
        ddsHeader.ddsPixelFormat.dwGBitMask == 0x0000FF00 &&
        ddsHeader.ddsPixelFormat.dwBBitMask == 0x00FF0000) 
    {
        format = GL_RGB8;
    }
    //etc
```

How to detect sRGB formats, for example `GL_COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT` or `GL_SRGB8_EXT` ? Does DDS support sRGB formats ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3D10 introduced image formats for sRGB images. [These formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgiformat/ne-dxgiformat-dxgi_format) could be used in an [extended version of the DDS format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddds/dx-graphics-dds-pguide#dds-variants), thereby allowing such files to declare that they contain sRGB data. Including block-compressed versions.

However, this requires both a compressor and a loader that supports DDS-10. You can tell if a loader supports DDS-10 if it checks the FOURCC for `"DX10"` and uses the `DDS_HEADER_DXT10` header to get a `DXGI` format. The testing code you showed does not appear to do so.